# Is sucrose made of 2 glucose molecules or 1 glucose and 1 fructose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbohydrates

I have read from several sources about sucrose and some say it is 2 glucose molecules and some others say it is 1 glucose molecule and 1 fructose molecule.

I know that both of these are related disaccharides since they have the same molecular formula of $\ce{C12H22O11}$

So which one is actually sucrose and what is the other disaccharide.

Comment: This was discussed recently here on Chemistry SE  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14562/why-do-other-sugars-melt-whereas-sucrose-decomposes   I checked a number of other links and all agree that sucrose is glucose + fructose

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because it is about the structure of 2 related sugars, not the melting point of sugars.

Comment: Yes, but the link shows the structure of sucrose and identifies the two monosaccharides.

Comment: but several sources I have read said that sucrose is glucose + glucose.

Comment: maltose is glucose+glucose

Comment: @ron - it is true that the answer can be found in other places, but that doesn't make this a duplicate question. OP is asking directly about the structure, so to be a duplicate, the other *question* (not answer) would have to be about the structure of glucose as well.

Comment: @caters - if you would link or reference your sources, someone can probably help clear up your confusion. At this point all anyone can say is "if your source says sucrose is two glucose molecules, then your source is wrong."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sucrose is composed of one glucose and one fructose monosaccharide.  Two glucose molecules form maltose.